# Inverting $3 \times 3$ matrix via Gauss-Jordan, cannot find my mistake

Tags: matrices, inverse

Can't find my mistake trying to find the inverse:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you do $R_2 \to R_2-2R_3$ on the 2nd page, you get in the 1st column $\frac23-2\times\frac19=\frac13$, while it should be $\frac49$.

Comment: Thanks a lot very helpful